# Can I mirror backwards?

Tags: modifiers, mirror

I want to mirror a building across the Y-axis, but I want the mirrored side to be flipped along the X-axis (I.E. be flipped). Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If you mirror/flip an object in two axis you get the same result as rotating it 180° around the other axis. Is that what you mean? Alt+D duplicates an object with linked data, so you can rotate the copy to where you want it and retain the possibility to edit both parts at the same time.

Comment: By the way - "...to be flipped along the X-axis (I.E. be flipped)" here I.E. or id est means “in other words” while "flipped" is the same word you already used - makes little sense.

Comment: My answer to a different question may help you here. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163243/mirrored-object-is-misaligned-when-compared-to-its-source-object/163249#163249

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to make a  linked duplicate of your original object (ALT+D) and then rotate it 180 degrees on the z axis. They will technically be separate objects, unlike  a modifier, but editing one will change the other accordingly.

Comment: ... which you could also do with a 180-rotated object-offset array modifier.