# Problem with Mirror Modifier and allignement

Tags: mirror, mirror-modifier

I was following the instruction of Blender Guru to realize a chair, I'm stuck in the part of mirroring, because the mirrored object apper to be in the wrong position  , in my case in the other part of the origin (look at the image, it's more clever) [image]
Maybe is something really simple, but I don't know what I'm missing.
I have alse tried to do what it's written there: [Mirrored object is misaligned when compared to its source object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163243/mirrored-object-is-misaligned-when-compared-to-its-source-object)
[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, what do you mean by wrong position? meybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi, my purpose is that the two pieces are close enought to look as one object

Comment: it seems to work as it is supposed to, here, the origin is the center of the mirror. Sometimes it is tilted compared to the global axis but it's because the local axis has been rotated

Comment: Ok, I do it in the wrong way, I must apply the mirror before cutting the original piece, but why?

Comment: what do you mean by cutting the original piece? I think you're on the right way, follow the tutorial

Comment: or please pack the image (File > External Data > Pack All into Blend) and share the file so that we can check: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: At the beginning I have this piece of the chair, the right way of do it is: 1)add mirror modifier 2)Delete an half of the verticies

Comment: I add an image of the final result, now the can overlap on each other, but I inverted step 2 and 1

Comment: it's not clear, are you trying to mirror each leg or the whole chair? these are 2 different things... if you want each leg to be symmetrical to itself, you can use a mirror, then apply the mirror, then create the whole chair

Comment: I was trying to mirror each leg, anyway, I'm really sorry to be so unclear, thanks for your time @moonboots

Comment: ok nice to know that you fixed your problem  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing the operation in the wrong order, the right one is:

1. Add mirror modifier
2. Cut the part that you want to be mirrored in 2 half
3. Delete the vertices of one half

I swapped the first 2 steps

[image]